# Firefox refuses to load @webfont--but inconsistently

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, font-face

Aright, here's my problem. I've got two @webfont declarations being used on my page:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'BebasNeue';
src: url('.../bebasneue-bebasneue.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('.../bebasneue-bebasneue.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); /* IE6-IE8 */
src: url('.../bebasneue-bebasneue.woff') format('woff'); /* Modern Browsers */
src: url('.../bebasneue-bebasneue.ttf')  format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS * 
src: url('.../bebasneue-bebasneue.svg') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */

}
@font-face {
font-family: 'ChunkFive';
src: url('.../chunksix-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('.../chunksix-webfont.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); /* IE6-IE8 */
src: url('.../chunksix-webfont.woff') format('woff'); /* Modern Browsers */
src: url('.../chunksix-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype') ;/* Safari, Android, iOS *
src: url('.../chunksix-webfont.svg') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Both load just fine in Chrome (latest). Only the second one works in Firefox (latest). Neither work in Internet Explorer 11.
I'm...honestly kind of stumped. I've got declarations for pretty much every conceivable browser, I've tried it with only src: declarations for the first two url's (as is typically used) (didn't change a thing)...I suppose it would be less of a conundrum if it were an all-or-nothing deal on each browser, but why does Firefox only support one?
Note: I'm working in Tumblr and loading fonts from static.tumblr.com.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This may not help Firefox, but i believe your declaration for eot 'IE6-IE8' should have a '?' before '#iefix' for the parser.

Answer (score 0):

What web server are you hosting your site on? Is it set up to serve all of those file types? In IIS, for example, you will have to add MIME types to serve up .woff, etc. You should fire up [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler), point Firefox at your page, and see if Firefox is actually getting the font files you expect, or if it's getting 404 or other errors.

Also, here is a typical font stack I use for cross-browser compatibility. It was originally developed by [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/):

```
@font-face{
font-family:"AmbleLight";
src: url('../fonts/Amble-Light-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/Amble-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
     url('../fonts/Amble-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/Amble-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/Amble-Light-webfont.svg') format('svg')
}
```

Also, I just noticed that you have three dots in your URLs. Is this on purpose? Should be 2 to "go up" one directory from your css file, or start with slash if absolutely located.

Comment: Everything is through Tumblr, so...I suppose their servers? Fiddler seems to indicate that Firefox is getting the .woff files, at least, which should suffice. I'm not familiar with Fiddler, though, so I might be misreading something important.